# 'qt' parameter does not work in search call of SolrPhpClient

Tags: php, solr

I am using SolrPhpClient for interacting with Solr via PHP.

I am using a custom request handler ( /select_test ) with 'edismax' feature in Solr config file

```
  <requestHandler name="/select_test" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <!-- Query settings -->
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="qf">
          text name topic description
       </str>
       <str name="df">text</str>
       <str name="mm">100%</str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="rows">10</str>
       <str name="fl">*,score</str>

       <str name="mlt.qf">
          text name topic description
       </str>
       <str name="mlt.fl">text,name,topic,description</str>
       <int name="mlt.count">3</int>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

I set the value for **'qt'** parameter as '/select_test' in the `$search_options` array and pass it as parameter to the search function of the **Apache_Solr_Service** as below:

```
$search_options = array(
    'qt' => '/select_test',
   'fq' => 'topic:games',
   'sort' => 'name desc'
);



$result = $solr->search($query, 0, 100000, $search_options);
```

It does not call the request handler at all. The call goes to the default '/select' handler in solr config file.

Just to confirm I put the custom request handler code in default handler and it worked.

Why is this happening? Am I not setting it right?

Please help!